# How do you create a Sitecore pipeline processor that runs when a new item is upload to the Media Library

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I would like to build a Sitecore pipeline processor that would grab the ID of a media item when it is uploaded and save that ID to an existing custom database that is used by a third-party application.

I have been unable to locate any How-to or examples on how to do this?

I am using Sitecore 8.0 Update 5 and an MVC structure for my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check in the `uiUpload` pipeline, but that will not fire for programatically created items, i.e. it will only fire when a user uploads an item via the CMS interface.

Create a new processor class:

```cs
public class ExternalSystemProcessor
{
    public void Process(UploadArgs args)
    {
        foreach (Item file in args.UploadedItems.Where(file => file.Paths.IsMediaItem))
        {
            // Custom code here
            SaveToExternalSystem(file.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

And then patch the in after the default save processor:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <processors>
      <uiUpload>
        <processor type="MyProject.Custom.Pipelines.ExternalSystemProcessor, MyProject.Custom" mode="on"
                   patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
      </uiUpload>
    </processors>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember any pipeline that would be executed when a new item is uploaded to media library, but you should be able to use `item:created` event.

Just check if the item from the args (`ItemCreatedEventArgs`) is media item and execute your code.

```cs
public void OnItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var createdArgs = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as ItemCreatedEventArgs;

    if (createdArgs != null)
    {
        if (createdArgs.Item != null)
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check if an item is media using `item.Paths.IsMediaItem`